# No Log file created in my Laravel storage folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

There is a registration form in my laravel website. There is no error given in the `console` while submitting the form using Ajax in my local server but after uploading the website in the live server while i submitting the form I have got below error in `console`

> 409 (Conflict)

And also there is no `log` file created in my live server that's why I can't understand the actual error.

So my question is

Why no `log` file created in `storage` folder in live server while there is an error?

How to solve that?

Comment: Make sure those folders have the correct write permissions. It's the web servers user that must have write access to them.

Comment: Check `config/logging.php` default or .env `LOG_CHANNEL` and see what the logging is set to.

Comment: `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/laravel && chmod 775 -R /var/www/laravel` for setting the right permissions